# Trying to use tools.jar - gradle

Tags: java, gradle, tools.jar

I am using `gradle` to package some java code into a jar. I am using some classes from `tools.jar`. I have had success in `gradle` building it and making a jar, but when I run that jar using `java -jar <package>.jar` I get the folowing
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine`.

Since `tools.jar` is something you get with a `jdk`, not a `jre`. Is there a way I can bundle `tools.jar` with my `package.jar` and have my jar work anywhere?

Here is my `build.gradle` so far.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }    
}

description = "A java program"

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs System.properties['java.home'] + '/../lib'
    }
}


jar {
    archiveName = "jProg.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Dependencies': 'com.sun.tools'
        )
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.sun', name: 'tools'

}
```

Comment: Probably what you need is called 'fat jar' (Gradle packs all dependencies to single jar)

Comment: @MaxFarsikov can you put it up as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you need is called 'fat jar' (Gradle packs all dependencies to single jar)

Comment: Some one downvoted this, my upvote only made it zero :(